# Add flag to each item in list

Tags: bash, mutt

I wanted to attach a list of png's to an email with mutt so I did this

```
attachment=""
for png in $(ls *.png); do attachment="$attachment -a $png"; done
mutt $attachment
```

To get this command `mutt -a pic1.png -a pic2.png -a pic3.png`. Any better ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Side note: [do not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Simply use `for png in *.png` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mutt` will accept the command as:

```
mutt -apic1.png -apic2.png -apic3.png
```

(with no space between `-a` and the filename), a wonderful possibility is the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob

files=( *.png )
mutt "${files[@]/#/-a}"
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` so that a non-matching glob expands to nothing.

The expansion of `"${files[@]/#/-a}"` will be like the expansion of `"${files[@]}"`, but with `-a` prepended to each field.

This is 100% safe if you have filenames with spaces or other funny symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BASH arrays:

```
arr=(*.png)
printf " -a %s" "${arr[@]}";
```

Comment: nifty, and also +1 for never using `ls` for iterating over files.